# Correct structure of a TCP/IP packet

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying to learn about network protocols and decided to try to implement the TCP protocol to see how it works.

However I haven't even been able to send a single TCP packet successfully.

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getMacAddress(const char *interface, unsigned char *macAddress)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sockfd;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, interface, IFNAMSIZ);

    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) == -1) {
        perror("ioctl");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }

    memcpy(macAddress, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}

void printBinary(char array[], size_t size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if(array[i] & 1)
                printf("1");
            else
                printf("0");
            array[i] >>= 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int packet_socket = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, ETH_P_IP);

    const char* interface = "wlp3s0";
    unsigned char macAddress[6];
    getMacAddress(interface, macAddress);

    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
    socket_address.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    socket_address.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex(interface);
    socket_address.sll_hatype = 0;
    socket_address.sll_pkttype = PACKET_OTHERHOST;
    socket_address.sll_halen = 6;
    memcpy(socket_address.sll_addr, macAddress, 6);

    int res = bind(packet_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
    
    unsigned char rawPacket[] =
    {
    // IPv4 Header
    0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x28,  // Version, IHL, Type of Service, Total Length
    0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,  // Identification, Flags, Fragment Offset
    0x40, 0x06, 0xA6, 0xEC,  // Time to Live, Protocol (TCP), Header Checksum
    0x17, 0x79, 0x4F, 0xFD,  // Source IP Address 
    0xC0, 0xA8, 0x2B, 0x41,  // Destination IP Address (Google's IP)

    // TCP Header
    0xDC, 0xB6, 0x01, 0xBB,  // Source Port, Destination Port (443)
    0xC7, 0x9B, 0x13, 0xD6,  // Sequence Number
    0x6A, 0xF5, 0xB5, 0xA7,  // Acknowledgment Number
    0x80, 0x10, 0x01, 0xF5,  // Data Offset, Flags, Window Size
    0x16, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00,  // Checksum, Urgent Pointer
    };

    
    int bytes = send(packet_socket, (const void*)&rawPacket[0], sizeof(rawPacket), 0);
    printf("%d\n", bytes);

    char buffer[300];
    int size = recv(packet_socket, &buffer, 300, 0);
    printf("%d\n", size);


    printBinary(buffer, size);


    close(packet_socket);
}
```

I used Wireshark to check the packet and it doesn't recognize it as TCP. Instead it says its protocol is "Logical-Link Control".

I also tried replacing the data with a random TCP packet I found in Wireshark, and this time it did recognize it as TCP.

It looks like the problem is with the data I'm sending, but everything seems to be correct, so I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: SOCK_DGRAM should be SOCK_RAW surely?

Comment: @user207421 I don't think that matters that much since I'm just using that socket to get the MAC address of the interface. I did try changing it to a raw socket, but it didn't affect anything.

Comment: Try SOCK_STREAM instead.

Comment: Have you compared the packet that worked with the packet that didn’t?

Comment: I compared just now, apparently I was completely ignoring the Ethernet header. I thought the socket took care of the link layer but that isn't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I compared just now, apparently I was completely ignoring the Ethernet header. I thought the socket took care of the link layer but that isn't the case.

Based on the comments, the main issue might be misunderstanding the layers at which your code operates and the structure of TCP/IP packets when sending them over a raw socket.
When using [`SOCK_RAW` with the `AF_PACKET` family](http://www.man-linux-magique.net/man7/PF_PACKET.html), you are working at the [link layer (Layer 2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer), which means you need to manually construct not only the [TCP (Layer 4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) and [IP (Layer 3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer) headers but also the Ethernet (Layer 2) header. That is likely why Wireshark is not recognizing your packets as TCP: because the necessary Ethernet header is missing.

```bash
+-------------------+
| Ethernet Header   |
+-------------------+
| IP Header         |
+-------------------+
| TCP Header        |
+-------------------+
| TCP Payload       |
+-------------------+
```

Try and prepend an Ethernet header to your packet data. The [Ethernet header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) typically includes the destination MAC address, source MAC address, and EtherType field indicating the type of payload (e.g., IPv4, IPv6).

Your `rawPacket` array would be:

```c
// Ethernet Header
unsigned char ethernetHeader[] = {
    // Destination MAC address (example, replace with actual)
    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
    // Source MAC address (your MAC address)
    macAddress[0], macAddress[1], macAddress[2],
    macAddress[3], macAddress[4], macAddress[5],
    // EtherType for IPv4
    0x08, 0x00
};

// Concatenate Ethernet Header and previous rawPacket
unsigned char fullPacket[sizeof(ethernetHeader) + sizeof(rawPacket)];
memcpy(fullPacket, ethernetHeader, sizeof(ethernetHeader));
memcpy(fullPacket + sizeof(ethernetHeader), rawPacket, sizeof(rawPacket));
```

You would need to send `fullPacket` instead of `rawPacket` with the `send` function.